# csv read columns and rows

Tags: csv, data-structures, python-3.x, numpy

Ok, so I have some data in a csv file, which looks roughly like this:

```
[fragment1, peptide1, gene1, replicate1, replicate2, replicate3]
[fragment1, peptide2, gene1, replicate1, replicate2, replicate3]
[fragment2, peptide1, gene2, replicate1, replicate2, replicate3]
[fragment2, peptide2, gene2, replicate1, replicate2, replicate3]
[fragment3, peptide1, gene2, replicate1, replicate2, replicate3]
```

And the problem is this - I need to use this data (the three replicates) in several different manners:

1. Over each row (i.e. just replicate1-3 for each row)
2. Over each replicate column for each fragment (i.e. replicate1 from peptides1 and 2 from fragment1, and the same for replicate2 and 3)
3. Over each replicate column for each gene (i.e. same as (2), but using genes instead of fragments

The data files all have the same columns, but the rows (i.e. number of fragments/peptides/genes) vary, so I have to read the data without specifying row numbers. What I need, essentially, is statistics (coefficients of variation) across each row, across each fragment and across each gene.

The variant across rows just uses the three replicates (always three values from one row), and is of course very simple to get to. Both the variants across fragments and across genes first calculates statistics for  using first statistics from every applicable replicate1, then every replicate2, then replicate3, (i.e. unknown number of values from unknown number of rows) and after that do the same statistics using the  values previously calculated (i.e. always three values).

I have a script that does this, almost, but it's very long and (I think) overly complicated. I basically read the file three times, each time gathering the data in the different manners described, monstly in lists and sometimes numpy.arrays.

In essence, my question is about how to best read data in different ways effectively, both speed-wise and "less code"-wise. I tried to find similar questions, to no avail. Any tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? I think pandas is very suited for this kind of data.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll check Pandas out and I'll ask on codereview as well - I didn't even know it existed!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt(open('myfile.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')

# 1 Access all rows
for row in data:
    print row

# Get all data in column 2 and 3
print data[:, (2,3)]
```

I'm not sure what you are asking in point 2 and 3. Can you provide sample input and expected output?